# Express server crash when new exception in async auth login function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This issue is making me crazy...
I have a throw exception making my express server crashing in my async login function.
The problem is that the error doesn't pass into the catch of the try/catch.
The user data is well received from database.

The new throw exception works fine if thrown outside of my bcrypt function.

```
module.exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {
      username,
      password
    } = req.body;
    if (!username) {
      throw new MissingRequiredParameterError({
        info: {
          body: ['usename']
        }
      });
    }

    if (!password) {
      throw new MissingRequiredParameterError({
        info: {
          body: ['password']
        }
      });
    }
    const user = await User.find({
      username: username
    }).exec();

    // throw new BadCredentialsError({                 // Exception works fine
    //   message: 'Username or password is incorrect'  // if those lines
    // });                                             // are uncommented

    if (user != '') {
      await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, (errBcrypt, resBcrypt) => {
        if (!resBcrypt) {                              // is false if password is wrong
          throw new BadCredentialsError({ // Line 85 THIS Exceptions makes my server crash if password is wrong !
            message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
          });
        } else {
          // Generate token
          const {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken
          } = await generateToken(user[0]);

          await res.json({
            accessToken,
            accessTokenExpiresIn: config.accessToken.expiresIn,
            refreshToken,
            refreshTokenExpiresIn: config.refreshToken.expiresIn
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new BadCredentialsError({
        message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
      });
    }


  } catch (err) {
    console.error('pass', err.stack);
    next(err);
  }
};
```

See the crash :

```
C:\Users\rebeb\Attila\attila-srv\api\controllers\auth.js:85
          throw new BadCredentialsError({
                ^
bad_credentials: Username or password is incorrect
    at C:\Users\rebeb\Attila\attila-srv\api\controllers\auth.js:85:17 {
  jse_shortmsg: 'Username or password is incorrect',
  jse_info: {},
  isHTTPError: true,
  status: 401,
  expose: true
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should instead be something to this effect:

`var resBcrypt = await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password);` Before continuing without a callback.

What is happening is that the error is being thrown within the callback itself, and not within the same code flow as the await call.

If the method does not support promise-based syntax you may have to "promisify" the method first.

https://javascript.info/promisify

Comment: Thanks my friend ... problem solved.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: No worries, super happy to help! Make sure to mark this answer as solved. Best of luck!